# what is the equivalent of visual basic withevents and handles in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, timer, handles

I try to convert a Visual Basic (VB) project to C# and I have no idea how to change some of codes below,

In a windows form a field and a Timer object defined like this;

```
Public WithEvents tim As New Timer
...
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tim.Tick
End Sub
...
```

How to rewrite this lines in C#?

Comment: If your rewriting this into a new c# winforms project, you presumably have a designer window, just add a new timer and double click it.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent for WithEvents in C#.   It relies on compiler magic in the VB.NET compiler that the C# compiler does not have.  First convert the VB.NET code to use the AddHandler statement instead, then you'll have a very easy time converting it to C#, a machine can do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C# you enrol an `EventHandler` by registering a method delegate with the event using the `+=` operator as follows:

```
public Timer tim = new Timer();
tim.Tick += Timer1_Tick;

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Event handling code here
}
```

This works because the `Tick` event of the `Timer` class implements an `Event` as follows:

```
public event EventHandler Tick
```

and `EventHandler` is a method delegate with signature:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(
    Object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

which is why any method that conforms to the `EventHandler` signature can be used as a handler.